# How should I allocate expenses for rental property with mixed personal use where the expenses are only for business use?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, rental-property

I have a house in California, USA, that I offer as a short term rental.

In 2022 it was 95% business use.
In 2023 it was 20% business use.
In 2024 I expect it to be 95% business use again.

I have expenses for the property which are only related to business use. For example I have it professionally cleaned after it is rented.

Thus the cleaning costs are not related to personal use even though I used the property personally most of the time during the year.

How should I handle these cleaning expenses? May I deduct any percentage of them and, if so, what percentage?

Comment: There are probably web pages discussing how to report AirBNB on your taxes; sounds like your   business is very close to that. I can't tell you which if those pages might be especially good or bad, but searching for "Airbnb income tax" is probably a good start.

Comment: I'm more asking because the property changed from "mostly business use" to "mostly personal use" which I think affects how I should file

Comment: Many AirBNBs are mostly personal use. I still think that's your best search term.